# Residual wait time of renewal process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, computer-science, point-processes

A paper[1] points out the fact that:

If we model the Email activity pattern as a renewal process [2] with interevent time distribution $P(\tau)$ then the generation time is the residual waiting time and is characterized by the probability density function [2]
$$g(\tau)=\frac{1}{\langle\tau\rangle} \int_{\tau}^{\infty} P(x) d x.$$
Where $\langle\tau\rangle=\int_0^{\infty} \tau P(\tau) d\tau$ is the mean interevent time.

I don't understand how this formula was obtained, and I didn't find an answer for it in the book [2]. Does this formula contradict the classic "waiting time paradox" or does it have anything to do with it?

Thanks a lot for any comments!

[1] V. Alexei, et al, Phys. Rev. Lett. 98, 158702(2007).
https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.98.158702

[2] W. Feller, *An Introduction to Probability Theory and its Applications* (Wiley, New York, 1966), Vol. II.

Comment: Could it be that your mixing the cumulative distrivition $P(\tau)=P(L_t\leq x)$ with its density, $P'(\tau)=p(\tau)$,  and using it as same?